# How can I make emails stack in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, email, email-client, incoming-mail

So I am developing an app that sends email notifications when people post and reply to a group. Example interaction might be:

- I make a post. Everyone in my group receives a notification.
- Barry replies to my post. Everyone receives another notification.
- Steve replies to my post too. Everyone receives another notification.

The notification email is sent as though it was sent by whoever made the post/reply (this is important and can't be changed). So the from name is me/Barry/Steve, and the from email is that person's email. The subject line for each email is the subject of the initial post, and so is the same for each notification for a given post.

I would like these notifications to stack in Gmail and other clients. However, Gmail (and presumably other clients) doesn't deal with stacking them very well. It stacks all of the emails from the same person with the same subject, but not the whole conversation. So I end up with a thread that contains all the replies Barry made to a post, and another thread that contains all the replies that Steve made to a post. I would obviously like these to weave together sensibly.

I think that the in-reply-to email header is key, but I am not sure how. Many thanks!

Comment: I am looking for exactly same info - why have you closed this???

Comment: I was looking for something similar. Any alternatives ?